# read a new SMS and afterwards change the status to 'read'. Windows Universal app

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, sms, win-universal-app

I can read a new SMS with this code

```
 Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessageStore store = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessageManager.RequestStoreAsync();
        var msgList = store.GetMessageReader();

        IReadOnlyList<Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessage> a = await msgList.ReadBatchAsync();

        foreach (var item in a)
        {
            if (item.IsSeen)
            {

               Don't do anything.. SMS is Readed
            }
            else
            {

             item.IsSeen=True (This not work because don't save this               status)    }
```

I try Mark IsSeen but its not work... Any Idea?

Comment: I found this instructions : markasreadasync and markasseenasync but I don't know how can I use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MarkAsSeenAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.chat.chatmessagestore.markasseenasync.aspx) as written on MSDN marks all transport messages as seen. 
So if you use

```
store.MarkAsSeenAsync()
```

you will mark all messages

But you can use second override

```
store.MarkAsSeenAsync(IIterable(String))
```

As IIterable(String) you can use collection

```
List<string>
```

with message id's.
Your code will look like this:

```
 Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessageStore store = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessageManager.RequestStoreAsync();
 var msgList = store.GetMessageReader();
 IReadOnlyList<Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessage> a = await msgList.ReadBatchAsync();

 List<string> l = new List<string>();

 foreach (Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessage item in a)
 {
     if (!item.IsSeen) l.Add(item.Id);
 }

 await store.MarkAsSeenAsync(l);
```

Comment: Hey Bro You Are the best.. You give me the idea.. Only was need this line: await  store1.MarkMessageReadAsync(item1.Id); Thanks so much!.. I Can't leave you a point because and a newbie but really thanks!!

Comment: Thank you, @abraham. Even if you new here, I think you can mark as answer.

Comment: Hi buddy, not only with 15 points, I have 14 XD its really hard get some points here jejeje.. If you vote for my post I forward your point